# vertical alignment of text in a frame with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, framed

I want the text 'Duration' in vertical align. This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\footnotesize,draw,align=left] at (0.1,2) {Frame\\ Control};
\node[font=\footnotesize,draw,align=left] at (1.5,2) {Duration\\ \phantom{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is how it looks and how it should look:

[image]

I had to use `\phantom`, because of the highness of the frame 'duration'. Without this command, the frame would be just one line in high.

Comment: You could have used `minimum height` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First solution, declare a `minimum height` for both nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={draw, font=\footnotesize, align=left, minimum height=1cm}]
\node[mynode] (FC) {Frame\\ Control};
\node[mynode, right=-\pgflinewidth of FC] {Duration};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second solution: Use a multipart rectangle. The height is fixed by the heighest node there's no need for guessing a `minimum height`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={draw, font=\footnotesize, align=left, 
            rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
            rectangle split horizontal}]
\node[mynode] (FC) {Frame\\control\nodepart{two}Duration};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works! In case i want to draw a third or a fourth [...] box, what is the right syntax? I have to define the last box everytime, is there a way to count an integer for each box, till it reaches the last box, and draw everytime a new one?

Comment: @ipo The correct syntax for which solution? Trying to understand the rest of your comment and from your nodes contents I guess you want to draw a IEEE 802.11 frame, which is a complete different question.